# FreeBSD 9.3 and OSX color tags

Tags: osx, colors, cp

I am using `nas4Free 9.3.2` and `FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p22`.

I noticed after using `cp`, that my moved files no longer had the color coded labels I had applied in *OSX*. Share mounted in *AFP*.  To test this, I made a folder `test1` and turned it red in *OSX*.  Then I ran this command:

```
cp -a -v /mnt/Storage1/test1 /mnt/Storage2/test2
```

and this one

```
cp -a -p -v /mnt/Storage1/test1 /mnt/Storage2/test2
```

In both instances, the file is copied, but the color label is missing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known limitation of the colored labels feature: the labels are known only by OSX's Finder, and if the files are copied by some other mechanism, Finder cannot detect this.

For further reading:

- [Mac OS X v10.5, 10.6: Finder label changes to files/folders mounted via SMB may not appear to other clients](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203372)
- [Color Labels not holding on shares (10.4.2 server)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1942747?start=0&tstart=0)
- [Color-coded files in MacOSX](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7733)
- [Over what protocol am I currently connected to a given server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145847/over-what-protocol-am-i-currently-connected-to-a-given-server)